# HTML scraping: iterating through nested directories

Tags: python, html, iteration, web-scraping

I need to scrape a website that has a basic folder system, with folders labled with keywords - some of the folders contain text files. I need to scan all the pages (folders) and check the links to new folders, record keywords and files. My main problem ise more abstract: if there is a directory with nested folders and unknown "depth", what is the most pythonc way to iterate through all of them. [if the "depth" would be known, it would be a really simple for loop). Ideas greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple spider algorithm. It uses a [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for documents to be processed and a set of already processed documents:

```
active = deque()
seen = set()

active.append(first document)

while active is not empty:
    document = active.popleft()
    if document in seen:
        continue

    # do stuff with the document -- e.g. index keywords

    seen.add(document)
    for each link in the document:
         active.append(link)
```

Note that this is iterative and as such can work with arbitrary deep trees.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it's working well. However I think there's a mistake: deque object doesn't have an add atribute, it should be append.

Comment: @priilane: you're welcome. My post is rather pseudo code than working python... nevertheless, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is usually the easiest way to go.

However, that might give you a StackOverflowError after some time if someone creates a directory with a symlink to itself or a parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me that both answers to the question can solve the problem. However, as I am fairly new to Python/recursion, would it be possible for you to provide a small snippet of (pseudo)code to make it easier to compare these two options.